# Long text and responsiveness of Angular UI accordion headers

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, css-float, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

So i am playing with the angular Bootstrap directives and am trying to implement the accordion control, with some info showing at the right part of each header.

```
<accordion-heading>
    some text here, on the left side of the header.

    <div class="pull-right">
        <span>1st info</span>
        <span>2nd info</span>
        <span>maybe 3rd?</span>
    </div>                
</accordion-heading>
```

here's the simplified plunkr:     http://plnkr.co/edit/3y0Rq1?p=preview

this shows well on medium to large screens but on smaller ones, the infos go under the header's line, and in some cases, scramble with the left text.

I'm sure there is a css trick to make this scenerio look right, by expanding the borders of the header in smaller screens, but cannot figure it out.

Help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, add a table with two columns in the head. First column has the data = "some text here, on the left side of the header." and the second column has the data = "1st info 2nd info maybe 3rd?"

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        some text here, on the left side of the header.
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <span>1st info</span>
          <span>2nd info</span>
          <span>maybe 3rd?</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I have made changes in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SU97GS?p=preview). Now when you make the window size small, the accordion header size increase accordingly. use float: left/right or pull-left/right to make further changes.

Hope it helps

Comment: does this solution work for you or are you facing any problems?